# Adding Score to score canvas after collision

Tags: unity, collision-detection, text

Simply a player has to move through pipes falling down, once the player moves through the gap it should add a score and increase the scoring after each pipe the player goes through, pretty basic.

I have made a prefab object and it is a block with a collider on it and another collider that acts as a trigger behind it stretched out so it can be accessed on both sides. I then added to the main scene canvas >> textmeshpro>>> added a script with the following code however, when the player hits the collider the score does not increase in the scene. But if I remove the GetComponent then it increases by increments of 4 in the inspector.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Score = 0;

    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>().text = Score.ToString();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        AddScore();
    }

    void AddScore()
    {
        Score++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you observe an error in the console when the GetComponent is present? Say, a Null Reference Exception or a Missing Reference Exception?

Comment: Yeah, I got rid of the getcomponent and the score comes up in my inspector but does not transfer to the score UI which is "0". Sorry I am new to all of this.

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Game.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Game.cs:17) That appears but when I remove the getcomponent the message does not appear.

Comment: Your problem is that you do not have a `Text` component attached to the same game object as this script is running on. You will likely want to expose a `public UnityEngine.UI.Text scoreField;` as a member variable that you can assign in the Unity Inspector. Then you can update `scoreField.text = Score.ToString();` inside your `AddScore` method.

Comment: Apologies I don't really understand how to actually implement it on the code.

Comment: Put the declaration of the public scoreField variable up near where you've defined your Score integer. Then put the text assignment just after your `Score++;` increment. You can see more examples of how to fix this at the duplicate linked above.

Comment: Still not working as it is not allowing me to drag in my scoreField (which is called ScoreText in mine) into the inspector.

Comment: What type is the score text, and what type is the variable? Be sure they're both scene objects, as you cannot reference a scene object from a prefab.

Comment: Figured out the problem was that I was using textmeshpro instead of normal text component and was writing public Text in the declaration so I just changed the scoring canvas from TMP to Text haha you live and learn.